# Power flow set Sharepoint list thumbnail field

Tags: powerapps, power-automate

I create a Sharepoint list with "thumbnail" field which will show as an image column.

[image]

I try to update `TestImage` from Power flow with "Send an HTTP request to SharePoint".

I know we can update "Hyperlink" field like `TstImage` below:

```
{
"__metadata": {
"type": "SP.Data.ListListItem"
},
"Image": {
"Description": "Google",
"Url": "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.jtzLV8nbTiaPVkbonKgPJAHaDk?pid=ImgDet&rs=1"
}
}
```

But, I need the "thumbnail" field type

Comment: Any reason why you’re not using the inbuilt connectors?

Comment: For `Thumbnail`, it is not available inbuilt connectors.